# Looking for an introductory text to complex analysis from a topological viewpoint

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

After taking topology and real analysis I realized that there's a lot of elementary stuff that can be tackled from both sides, is there any book that deals with introductory complex analysis from the perspective and using the tools of topology?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Perhaps give an example of a complex analysis theorem with a purely topological proof?

Comment: I'd say that topology becomes really useful after, when studying functional analysis, or complex analysis of several variables, or...

Comment: @lhf I have seen some basic stuff from real analysis proved with topology but nothing from complex analysis that's why I'm asking if theres a book where that has some.

Comment: I recall exactly such a book, which I used to see in my university's library in the 1970s, but I can't recall the title or author. I *think* it was published by Van Nostrand (maybe in the Van Nostrand Reinhold Mathematical Studies series of books). Perhaps a complex analyst will know which book I'm thinking of. It would have been published sometime in the 1960s or 1970s.

Comment: @ Dave L. Renfro - Thanks, with your information I've found three candidates - Complex manifolds without potential theory by S.S. Chern ---- Topics in the theory of functions of one complex variable by W. H. J. Fuchs ; manuscript prepared with the collaboration of Alan --- Lectures on the theory of functions of a complex variable by George W. Mackey Schumitsky. Any of those ring a bell? All three were published in 1967.  I'll have a look at them when I go the the library and update.

Comment: It just so happens I was at a nearby university library yesterday (for other reasons), so I looked though the complex analysis books for the book I remember seeing at the university I was an undergraduate at in the 1970s. I didn't see the book I was thinking of. However, *Lectures On The Theory Of Functions Of A Complex Variable* by George W. Mackey might be the book I'm thinking of. I tried to find a review of it to be sure, but I wasn't able to find a review. But if it's the book I'm thinking of, you'll know from reading the book's preface.

Comment: There is a review of Mackey's book at the [Zbl archive](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0162.09401) (select "Show Scanned Page"). I'm still not sure it's the book I'm thinking of, but I am a little more sure after seeing this review. It might be the case that the book uncharacteristically (for when it was published) begins with topological notions, and at the time I took this to be a heavy topological flavor throughout the book (and possibly I might think differently now). Nonetheless, I seem to recall the preface (of the book I'm thinking of) saying the book makes more than usual use of topology.